# Cover the Earth and you will not see

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, plagues-makkos, bo

Why by the Locusts does it use the repetitive language: I will cover the eye of the land and you will not see it, if it is covered of course you can not see it?

וְכִסָּה אֶת עֵין הָאָרֶץ וְלֹא יוּכַל לִרְאֹת אֶת הָאָרֶץ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kli Yakar explains based on the Gemara in Yoma 74: "Suma Ain lo Seviya" (a blind person is always hungry as he does not see the food) that the grasshoppers themselves could not see the ground and thus they ate even more than usual.

Answer (score 3):

Onkelos (if I understand him right) says *en haaretz* means "the sight of the sun".